# Model is not giving correct results even if accuracy is good

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencl, prediction, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a project to translate sign language to english. As a part of this i used google's teachable machine application to create dataset and train the model.I downloaded the trained .tflite model and developed opencv application for it to predict in live.
The python code is as follows

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.lite as tflite
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
with open("labels.txt", 'r') as f:
    labels =  [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
print(labels)
interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path="model_unquant.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
print(input_details)
input_index = input_details[0]['index']

def predict(image_data):
    input_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, axis=0).astype(np.float32)  # expand to 4-dim
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_index,input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    output_data = np.squeeze(output_data)
    print(len(output_data))
    print(output_data)
    top_k = output_data.argsort()[-len(output_data):][::-1]
    print(top_k)
    a = []
    for i in top_k:
        sign = labels[i]
        print(sign)
        score = output_data[i]
        print(score)
        sign = labels[i]
        print(sign)
        score = output_data[i]
        a.append((sign,score))
    a = sorted(a, key = lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
    return a[0][0], a[0][1]
c = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
res, score = '', 0.0
i = 0
mem = ''
consecutive = 0
sequence = ''
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)    
    if ret:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = 200, 100, 424, 324
        img_cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        c += 1
        #image_data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img_cropped)[1].tostring()
        a = cv2.waitKey(1) # waits to see if `esc` is pressed
            
        if i == 4:
            res_tmp, score = predict(img_cropped)
            res = res_tmp
            i = 0
            if mem == res:
                consecutive += 1
            else:
                consecutive = 0
            if consecutive == 2 and res not in ['nothing']:
                if res == 'space':
                    sequence += ' '
                elif res == 'del':
                    sequence = sequence[:-1]
                else:
                    sequence += res
                consecutive = 0
        i += 1
        cv2.putText(img, '%s' % (res.upper()), (250,400), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255,255,255), 4)
        cv2.putText(img, '%.3f' % (float(score)), (200,450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255))
        mem = res
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (18,31,150), 3)
        cv2.imshow("img", img)
        img_sequence = np.zeros((200,1200,3), np.uint8)
        cv2.putText(img_sequence, '%s' % (sequence.upper()), (30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.imshow('sequence', img_sequence)
        if a == 27: # when `esc` is pressed
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

Using the downloaded model , i used opencv and wanted to do prediction in real time.
But the predictions are all wrong. They are completely wrong.
I guess all the labels are correct.
Link for teachable machine model and the .tflite,labels files

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y74e84tbnehfmg7/AAARPgxEoNZQeZZaUTk1I8eMa?dl=0
```

The output will be like
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps284.png)

the input_details of provided.tflite file are (by executing `interpretrt.get_input_details()`)

```
[{'name': 'serving_default_sequential_3_input:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3]), 'shape_signature': array([ -1, 224, 224,   3]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

In google's teachable machine , I made sure that all signs are correctly predicted ,but here all were predicted wrong,

I tested on sample image which is exactly (224*224) and sent for prediction , it is also displaying wrong prediction
The image i used is [image: P] for letter `P`

I used the code

```
img = 
cv2.imread("C:/Users/kaush/Desktop/project/asl_alphabet_test/P.jpg")
    res_tmp, score = predict(img)
    print(res_tmp , score)
```

How do i get correct prediction. How do i resolve it,

Comment: if your model performance is promising in the teachable machine, I would try saving the image from cv2 `img_cropped`, and once you feel your sample image looks good visually(as the model was trained on 224X224), then try to predict the saved image in the teachable machine. I somehow feel that the "data in"(image matrix) for the model is not matching what the model has been trained on!

Answer (score 0):

somehow I feel that https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train is more for prototype and it does not open all the opportunities to enhance the performance of the model. For example, not sure if it tweaks the images before feeding into training, can't change the depth of the model, etc.

I tried with `epochs=500, batch size=16`; with this change, I was able to predict the image you were trying, but when I feed the web images(via cv2), it worked for some, not for all.

try to look at under the hood metrics, all the metrics look so perfect :) (questionable)

recommendation:

1. if possible try to build a model in TensorFlow with hyperparameter optimization

All the code is at [github](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/Image_sign_to_letter)

```
img = Image.open('Screen Shot 2022-04-11 at 10.31.46 AM.png').convert("RGB")
img = ImageOps.fit(img, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
input_data = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
input_data /= 255.
input_data
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
#print(np.argmax(output_data[0]))
print("Predicted label : ",labels[str(np.argmax(output_data[0]))])# "P"
```

[Jupiter notebook with demo](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/Image_sign_to_letter/blob/main/teachablemachine%20-%20Demo_Quick%20Tour.ipynb)

[real time with cv2](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/Image_sign_to_letter/blob/main/TM_web_realtime.py)